# Starting Hololens emulator in mac using Vmaware and run Windows 10. getting error message

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization, hololens, hololens-emulator

"The emulator is unable to set some properties ...."

I want to start hololens emulator in mac. I installed Vmware and Windows 10 but I get the error message shown in the image when I want to run the emulator.
Could anyone help me to fix it or it cannot be achieved to start the emulator using virtual machine.?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lUTq.png)

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your memory allocation for your VMs, its looking for 8gigs, and you only have 5 gigs available for that vm. What I was able to do is to use bootcamp to boot to a windows os directly on the mac, and this will give you access to more memory in windows for your vm, but there is a bug where your virtualization in the MacOS will not automatically turn on, so you have to do it manually after you install bootcamp and windows 10. Then you need to make sure your hyper-V is installed in windows, so that requires windows 10 pro.

Comment: Hi there, You say "its looking for 8gigs" so I wonder if my MacBook that only has 8GB RAM would be suitable? I am thinking of using BootCamp on a Retina Early 2015 with 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3, but I have been reading some horror stories that it won't function properly on an 8GB laptop with Win10Pro installed via BootCamp. I wonder if you could tell me more please. Thanks

Comment: I have 16gig, I have never tried it with 8, so I am not sure what your experience would be like.

Comment: Thank you. So, you just installed Win10Pro via BootCamp and now you simply boot to Win10Pro every time you switch on your Mac and use the emulator with no problems. Correct?  Another question: When you say "you have to manually turn on your virtualization", are you referring to installing Hyper-V or do you mean some other thing that every time should be done to turn it on?  Thanks

Comment: You have to go into the Apple os and make sure that virtualization is turned on, it will say that it is, but turn it off and then on again, there is a bug in the Apple OS. Once you do that you will be able to use Hyper-V in windows 10

Comment: Got it!  Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Hyper-V (on which the official HoloLens emulator works) from VirtualBox or VMware.

As an alternative, you might try Boot Camp.

You can use Boot Camp to install Windows 10 on supported Mac models that have OS X Yosemite or later installed.

These are the supported models.

```
MacBook Pro (2012 and later)
MacBook Air (2012 and later)
MacBook (2015 and later)
iMac Pro (2017)
iMac (2012 and later)
Mac mini (2012 and later)
Mac mini Server (Late 2012)
Mac Pro (Late 2013)
```

To do an install of Windows, you'll also need Windows 10 installation media.

Then, open Boot Camp Assistant from the Utilities folder (or use Spotlight to find it) and use it to install a new copy of Windows.

[Here's a full instruction (and more details on this install) from Apple.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990)

(I use Windows, so it just works for me)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.